# How to sort Item in CListCtrl in MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I made a Dialog based application in MFC. I put CListCtrl control on my Dialog and set its view style to report type. I have five columns in this list view. All columns are of String type. I want to implement the sorting in this list, That is when I click on a column it should   sort item in the list. I saw many examples related to this. but none is working for me. Can some one guide me how to do that???

Thanks

Comment: Use a CMFCListCtrl to simplify your life. It supports multiple columns sorting and even color marking of sorted columns!

Answer (score 3):

Since it is MFC, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1360/Sort-List-Control) sample and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27774/CListCtrl-and-sorting-rows) sample should work.

Comment: my sort work once. if I click more than once, it gives unexpected results.

Comment: what does "unexpected results" mean? What is the delta between your results and the ones obtained from the samples provided?

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"**Provide context for links:** Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*