# CListCtrl items sorting when click on column header without using callback function

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have an mfc dialog-based application with a CListCtrl box in report view.
It has 4 columns, one is numeric value column and others are all text.
In my application I want to add sorting functionality when I click on any of the headers without using the callback function. And my list items are already populated in the listcontrol box from a database table when I start the application. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort Item in CListCtrl in MFC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578709/how-to-sort-item-in-clistctrl-in-mfc)

Comment: @RogerRowland Thank you. I have seen that. But the answers there does not work properly.

Comment: You might also like to use [CMFCListCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983191.aspx) instead, which has better support for sorting generally. However, asking for tutorials on this site is off-topic so you'll need to make some progress first and then ask a specific question.

Comment: I'm guessing that you do not want to use a callback, because you don't know how to populate List Control items with additional information required for sorting. The *lParam* member of the [LVITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760.aspx) structure is yours. Populate it with whatever you need to perform the sort in your callback. Otherwise, asking for a solution and preemptively discarding the canonical solution requires an explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your information@IInspectable.

Comment: @IInspectable: I had a different inerpretation: He/She does not want to use a callback because things already come sorted from the database. Like when he clicks on the *Name* column header, it puts `SORT BY NAME`on a SQL statement.

Comment: @sergiol: If a question leaves room for interpretation, it isn't a good question. By your interpretation, the question boils down to a simple UI state query of the header control.