# C++ MFC CListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have a CListctrl on a dialog with five columns :

1. Name of the file
2. Size of the file
3. Extension of the file
4. Version of the file
5. Last modified date of the file

I should provide user the option of sorting any column based on which all the other columns should get sorted.

I don't know how to proceed ?

I have all the data in a vector.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578709/how-to-sort-item-in-clistctrl-in-mfc.

Comment: Use a `CMFCListCtrl` to simplify your life. It supports multiple columns sorting and even color marking of sorted columns!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort Item in CListCtrl in MFC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578709/how-to-sort-item-in-clistctrl-in-mfc)